# AMD 6870 Twin Frozr II video adapter issues

Tags: 11.10, video, graphics, ati

Hardware: AMD 6870 Twin Frozr II (1GB), ASUS 990 chipset
Software: Ubuntu 11.10

Built a new PC from scratch, loaded it with Ubuntu 11.10. It's displaying, but with poor resolution, unable to change, as it says no drivers are installed.

Ubuntu indicates that there are 2 proprietary drivers available to download:

- ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX Graphics driver (Post-release update)
- ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX Graphics driver

The first won't even finish downloading.

The second downloads and installs, but when I restart the PC as requested it boots up, I see purple in the background, then the video feed just stops with a black screen. I can still hear ubuntu boot up though.

It seems like I just need the latest drivers, googled around and not had much luck. I'm pretty new with Ubuntu, but have basic knowledge. Any potentially helpful information would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` keys at the purple screen to you can access a terminal, login with your username and password.

Remove all the fglrx traces from your system:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

You should be back at using the open-source drivers and being greeted with your login screen.

After this install the drivers from ATI.

---

Download the newest ATI driver (current version is 11.11)

```
mkdir ~/ATI && cd ~/ATI
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once downloaded set the downloaded file to run as executable

```
chmod 755 ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

Build the packages for Ubuntu 11.10 and install them

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once the driver is installed you need to start up a new xorg.conf file with this command

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```